# How intelligent is excel when is "parses" a function in a cell that includes identical calls to the same function more than once

Tags: excel, worksheet-function, vba

Consider this: Cell `C1` has a formula that calls another function many times:

eg `=ExcelFuntionA(ExcelFunctionCallB(1), ExcelFunctionCallB(1)-1, ExcelFunctionCallB(1)-2, ExcelFunctionCallB(1)*3)`

Note that the parameter(s) passed to `ExcelFunctionCallB` have the same value(s) each time.

If `ExcelFunctionCallB(..)` is a function that involves significant processing, would excel process the formula quicker if the result of `ExcelFunctionCallB(..)` was found in anther cell and the above formula was changed to reference this cell 4 times.

eg

Say `A2` has the formula  `ExcelFunctionCallB(..)`
C1 would then read  `=ExcelFuntionA(A2, A2-1, A2-2, A2*3)`

I'm wondering how intelligent excel is!

1. Can is see that calls are identical and only process a call to the function once?
2. Is it intelligent enough to do this for array formulas as well as normal function formulas?
3. If you call a function that has been written in VBA how does it work?
   Bear in might that a VBA function could reference cells directly
   that are not passed as parameters ( I know this is naughty, but it
   happens, and there is only small chance that it might return a different
   value even if the parameters that are used with it are the same.)

Following on from the above, is there a way of telling the code that a VBA function does not access any excel cells directly?   (A bit like `application.volatile` I would imagine)

A more realistic example:  I've actually been experimenting with formulas like this:

`=MID($A2, FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE("#" & $A2 & "#","#","@",B$1)), FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE("#" & $A2 & "#","#","@",B$1+1)) - FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE("#" & $A2 & "#","#","@",B$1)) - 1 )`

which is well documented in one of the proposed by not approved answers to SO question 24182334/splitting-text-columns

Note that this formula uses the text `FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE("#" & $A2 & "#","#","@",B$1))` three times.

[PS. I know about split in VBA and the text to columns menu option.]

Comment: "If ExcelFunctionCallB(..) is a function that involves significant processing, would excel process the formula quicker if the result of ExcelFunctionCallB(..) was found in anther cell and the above formula was changed to reference this cell 4 times." This is correct, referencing an already calculated cell is faster than recalculating the same thing multiple times in an individual cell.  Excel will calculate each one separately

Comment: @tigeravatar your comment is the answer to the Q asked.  You should post as a _answer_

Comment: Great article.  Thanks.  I've learn a lot. I'm a bit disappointed it works like this, but I expected it would.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If ExcelFunctionCallB(..) is a function that involves significant
>   processing, would excel process the formula quicker if the result of
>   ExcelFunctionCallB(..) was found in anther cell and the above formula
>   was changed to reference this cell 4 times.

This is correct, referencing an already calculated cell is faster than recalculating the same thing multiple times in an individual cell. Excel will calculate each one separately

Also, as pointed out by pnuts, this link may be of interest: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff700515%28v=office.14%29.aspx

(posted as answer at chris neilsen's suggestion)

Answer (score 0):

The key text from the link in the above answer ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff700515%28v=office.14%29.aspx))   is

If you have a calculation-intensive formula where you want the result to be shown as zero if there is an error (this frequently occurs with exact match lookups), you can write this in several ways.

You can write it as a single formula, which is slow:

In cell A1   `=IF(ISERROR(time expensive formula),0,time expensive formula)`

You can write it as two formulas, which is fast:

In cell A1 `=time expensive formula`
In cell B1 `=IF(ISERROR(A1),0,A1)`

Starting in Excel 2007, you can use the IFERROR function, which is designed to be fast and simple, and it is a single formula:

In cell A1 `=IFERROR(time expensive formula,0)`

So the same logic would apply to other types of formulas it would seem.